# Geodata dropdown configurator not showing countries

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I decided to go with a shortcut method of getting a dropdown list of countries and states by using the geodata configurator:

```
<select name="country" class="countries order-alpha" id="countryId">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<select name="state" class="states order-alpha" id="stateId">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/countrystate.js"></script>
```

I get this to work perfectly in JSBin but I can not get it to work on my site (Flask/Jinja).

I copied and pasted as you see here (though I did move the script tags to the bottom above the {% endblock %} of my template).

The fact the code works on JSBin but just gives me nothing on my site: https://gyazo.com/a67c8f738e95d57efac2c74e426c37b1

Makes me believe this is some mixup with Python or another JS Script.

I have `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js "...` and `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">` both loading too (from the base template).

From what I can tell all the scripts have loaded. Any other reason why the dropdown select isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Andy, the developer of geodata.solutions.
It's difficult to say what the issue is without seeing your app, but the general things apply:
-Use the web developer console to see if anything is thrown up.
-My initial thoughts if no js errors are thrown is that you have another element with id countryId, and that's why it's not changing the dropdown.
-If you make a local copy of countrystate.js and use that, you can add console logs to the various events to see where the issue is. It's that initial function this.getCountries that you want to look at, which is triggered by the function at the bottom

```
jQuery(function() {
    var loc = new locationInfo();
    loc.getCountries();
    jQuery(".countries").on("change", function(ev) {
        var countryId = jQuery("option:selected", this).attr('countryid');
        if(countryId != ''){
            loc.getStates(countryId);
        }
        else{
            jQuery(".states option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });
    jQuery(".states").on("change", function(ev) {
        var stateId = jQuery("option:selected", this).val();
        if(stateId != ''){
            loc.confCity(stateId);
        }
    });

});
```

-I'm not a python dev, so if it is related to a conflict with python, then someone with that background might have experience.

Please let me know how you get on. Anything I can do to make it more platform-neutral is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me Andy. I appreciate it. I think I found the issue. I don't think your API is compatible with Materialize "select" elements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can I make a local copy of the countrystate.js? I am not familiar with how to find this file through your site. At the moment, I am building a JSON file which will solve my issue and will run it backend in python (when I work out how). But if I had the local file, that would save calling the API.